# Integrate UWP XAML with D3D11 Renderer

Tags: c++, xaml, mvvm, data-binding, uwp

As a little side project, I thought I'd take a look at creating a simple 3D application. I'm reasonably comfortable creating WPF applications, so the Visual Studio 'DirectX 11 and XAML App (UWP)' caught my eye. It should be mentioned that I am slowly working my way through the canonical book on D3D11, '3D Game Programming with with DirectX 11' by Frank Luna.

Thus, my comfort zone with D3D11 is quite narrow, but I felt confident enough to tackle a simple task. I fell at the first hurdle. What I was trying to do is take the Visual Studio template, add simple UI of a few text boxes to view and edit the model transform.

I came unstuck with how to connect my ViewModel for the UI with my C++/CX object that contains the 3d model, and thus the model transform. My class that defines the property of the 3dmodel is a standard C++ class. I don't seem to to be able to grasp how to marry the two together.

All the tutorials out there that I've come across leave out the most important part of XAML/D3D11 integration and that is data binding to the game/scene objects themselves.

So, the question: How do I tackle the task of bridging the gulf between my C++/CX ViewModel and C++ game objects?

Comment: [Data binding overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-quickstart) covers how to glue C++/CX ViewModel and C++ game objects. But game with mvvm is something unusual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just typical that after I post the question that I find direction towards an answer.

Microsoft in their Windows Universal Samples, has a sample 'Simple3DGameXaml'. It does use Xaml, but doesn't use controls and bind to them to game objects.

https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Simple3DGameXaml

However, it does show an alternative layout of the application that completely removes the confusion I had with connecting two seemingly different parts of the application.

Thanks.